# Python pandas regex very slow

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, regex-lookarounds

I have a pandas dataframe filled with text in several columns and about 20,000 rows. I need to do some string operations for what I chose regex. When using OR operators like

```
pattern = "string1|string2|string3"
```

its all fine and the script takes about a couple of seconds, which is ok.

But if I use the AND (lookarounds) expression like

```
pattern = "(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)(?=.*string3)"
```

its super slow. I mean obviously it needs to calculate more and more often but it takes several minutes to complete, even if I only use 2 strings.

Is there some way to make a more efficient AND regex algorithm which takes place in one line and is not chained like

```
contains(string1, flags=re.I, regex=True) & contains(string2, flags=re.I, regex=True)
```

thanks for possible help

Comment: why not put it in a database? if you got that many rows: database could be the way to go.

Comment: what do you mean by database? I am using a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I meant using a database for an example sqlite db and then calling Regex to search

Comment: Is the order of string1, string2 and string3 unspecified?

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little faster if we intersperse some anchors, but don't expect more than 10 % from that.

```
"^(?=^.*string1)(?=^.*string2)(?=^.*string3)"
```